# I can't add file or change file to github.com

Tags: github

I've created an account for github,and set up ssh at home and at my workplace. now I just want to renew and add files so that I do some operation like this:

```
jty@CVICSE-0E662498 ~/front-end-learn (master)
$ git remote add origin git@github.com：jtyjty99999/front-end-learn.git
jty@CVICSE-0E662498 ~/front-end-learn (master)
$ git push - u origin master
ssh:github.com:noaddress associated with name
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I failed T_T. At my workplace I used proxy to connect to Internet, does it matter? How can I solve this problem? thanks everyone cordially.

Comment: Have you followed [THIS](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/) help doc, especially for the `"Generate a new SSH key.
"` & `"Add your SSH key to GitHub."` steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are inputting the command wrong, I believe it is supposed to be this
`git push -u origin master`
(no space after the '-')

and you can double check the proper address by using 
`git remote -v`

edit: you also have to use the commands `commit` and `add` to actually tell git what to push

here is more [info](http://help.github.com/remotes/)

Comment: There also appears to be an extra space between `github.com:` and `jtyjty99999/...`